# Load data local infile not inserting into database

Tags: php, mysql, load-data-infile

I have a .CSV file which will import to mysql database, using Load data local infile syntax, my csv file contains 23 columns, but I want to import the selected columns only in database.

My problem is my load infile systax didnt import anything from my .CSV file.

Below is my code:

```
$mysql = printf("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'File.csv' INTO TABLE table
            FIELDS 
                TERMINATED BY ','
            LINES 
                TERMINATED BY '\\n'
            IGNORE 1 LINES 
            (column1, column2, column3...) 
");

$query = mysql_query($mysql);
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks a lot!

Comment: You are not doing any error checking. Use http://php.net/mysql_error to see what's wrong

Comment: What is the error message that you get? Add `or die(mysql_error)` after the call to `mysql_query`. Also use `Mysqli` instead as `Mysql_*` is deprecated

Comment: Hi @Pekka웃 Heres what I get. Error message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '221' at line 1

Comment: Hi @BOMEz here's my error checking code i have if(!$query) 
{
 printf("Error message: %s\n", mysql_error());  
}

Comment: Hi @BOMEz you mean my mysql_query() function is deprecated? I was aboout to change it to mysqli_query(). thanks

Comment: From your other comment it sounds like you have an error in your SQL syntax. Can you update your question with the full mysql query you enter? Currently you have `(column1, column2, column3...)`  which is incomplete.

Comment: Can you show the full statement?  Does `221` appear in your code?

Comment: Hi @Tom what statement? thanks

Comment: Hi @BOMEz column1..column2..column3 is the column name from my corresponding column in my csv file . example. column11 = Agent, column2 = ID, column3 = Address. here the statement, (Agent, ID, Address and so on and so fourth)

Comment: Hi thanks everyone, I already solve the issue. its more on the columns and executing.

Answer (score 2):

Login to your SSH prompt.

Then type

```
# mysql -u admin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow`;

mysql>LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'File.csv' INTO TABLE table
            FIELDS 
                TERMINATED BY ','
            LINES 
                TERMINATED BY '\\n'
            IGNORE 1 LINES 
            (column1, column2, column3...)
```

If it is working, the problem is with your database user permissions. Change database user permission and execute.

Answer (score 0):

On windows this is what i use. i use a remote db and still have to put in the extra slash for the files location dir "C:\" there appears to be and extra slash in both examples above '\n' 
i believe it should only be one. edit this and try it in mysql workbench or some similar GUI

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:\\resultItem.txt' 
INTO TABLE resultItem 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
 IGNORE 1 LINES
(ID, Accessibility, Assigned_To, AttachedFileCount, Category, `Change`,       Changed_By,Changed_Date,ChildLinkCount,Closed_By,Closed_Date,Dependent_Date,Dependent_Link_Status,Description, @insertedtothisDB)
 SET insertedtothisDB = utc_timestamp();
```